# Use JS to change background colour

Tags: javascript, html

I am an absolute beginner, and thought that I'd see if i could copy this seemingly basic project (http://jenniferdewalt.com/random_background.html). Rather than just copy the code, I want to figure out why I can't get it to work. I really have no idea how JS interacts with HTML. Here's what i've got:

HTML:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../CSS/randomcolor/randomcolour.css" />
<link type="text/javascript" src="../../JS/Random Colour/randomcolour.js">

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../JS/Random Colour/randomcolour.js"></script>

</head>
<body> 

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="randomColor()";>
<div .class="button" id="button">
  <h2></h2>
</div>
</a>
```

JS:

```
function randomColor() {
return '#' + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8);
};

var backgroundColor = randomColor()
```

This is all probably a million miles off the mark, so if anyone can point me to a resource that will help me out at all, it'd be much appreciated. It's so frustrating not being able to figure this out!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820733/getting-a-random-background-color-in-javascript

Comment: When you click the link, you call `randomColor()`, but you don't do anything with the return value.

Answer (score 3):

Use this function to generate a random color!

```
function get_random_color() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

And in your html, the period before `class` is not needed.

Then, set the body of the page with:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = get_random_color(); //or stick with randomColor();
```

It's also better practice not to use inline javascript, try setting the onclick event like this (removing it from the html)

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function() {
    //set body style here
}
```

Oh, one more thing: you're trying to use a `link` tag to reference a javascript file -- this will not work. That's for CSS!

Comment: Thanks for your help. so now i have:</head> <body> 
      <div class="button" id="button">
      <h2>Press Me!</h2>
</div> </body>                                                                           for the html

Comment: function get_random_color() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = get_random_color();
}Still not working, what do I need to do?

Comment: Depends, what does not working mean? Error messages? Debug statements?

Comment: When i preview the html page and click the button to run the function, nothing happens to the background. Do you know of any decent sites to pick up stuff like this, as I feel embarrassed asking things that should be obvious.

Comment: Just follow tutorials, google search keywords of your questions. Google is very helpful and SEO yields a lot of good Stack questions

Answer (score 1):

The formula is `Element.style.backgroundColor = '#000000;'`

Answer (score 1):

You are only storing the background color in a temporary variable, you need to store it into the backgroundColor css property of the body

so you need

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomColor()
```

where you want to change the background color.

For examlple you could put this directly in the onClick handler, or call function that does this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is this.... very easy.

a. first define a function that return random values so less writing.

b. input those into rgba ...

c. you have what you want.

```
function rand(x){return Math.round(Math.random()*x);}
document.body.style.backgroundColor='rgba('+rand(255)+','+rand(255)+','+rand(255)+','+rand(10)/10+')';
```